# In localhost docker login is successful, but from another machine I get Error response from daemon: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to deploy a docker registry in my server to manage our images.
I have created it with TLS authentication.

When I run command `docker login -u username [registry_domain]:[port]` in localhost docker login is successful.

When I'm running the same command from another machine I get:

```
Error response from daemon: Get [registry_domain]:[port] x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have added the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the next line, but it only solved the problem for localhost

```
{ "insecure-registries": ["registry:8443"] }
```

When checking the logs for the registry I can see the error:

```
 http: TLS handshake error from [remoteComputerIp]: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Has anyone encountered this situation? Or maybe could point me to the right direction? Can't seem to find a solution for this

Comment: Did you restart the docker daemon after changing `daemon.json`?

Comment: Yes, and it fixed the problem for localhost, but if I run the login command from another computer in the network, I get the error still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

In order to get the remote machines to be able to login to my registry, I had to copy the `client.crt` I generated when creating the registry into the default machine I was connecting from. This is because I was signing the certificates myself.

You can ssh into it by using `docker-machine ssh [name of the machine]` (in my case name was "default")

You copy the certificate to `/etc/docker/certs.d/<registry-domain>:<port>/ca.crt`

No need to restart anything. Once its working you can easily test by using the command `docker login -u username <registry-domain>:<port>`

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating certificates:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs machine-name
```

From: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-private-registry-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority/21262/3

Comment: This apparently helps sometimes. This wasn't the case but might be useful for others